# Calling objects and array from revealing module pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

```
var GlobalObject = (function(){

    var arr1 = [];
    var arr2 = [];
    var arr3 = [];
    var arr4 = []; 

        return {

         }

})();
```

1. Now how would i call GlobalObject.arr1 across the application?
2. Will it maintain its reference and value, when i do a push and pop.
3. Will this cause any memory leak

Comment: What do you mean by memory leak?

Comment: @Bergi: Will it pollute my namespace by creating new objects.

Comment: currently, your namespace is empty. And of course this code creates a few objects, but that's its purpose, isn't it?

Comment: @Bergi: Will it get garbage collected automatically since its in closure.

Comment: As it stands, yes. It won't if you export any functions that have access to the variables.

Comment: @Bergi: you meant to say that if i an return out any function which have access to these variables... then there is a memory leak

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23315/discussion-between-kevin-and-bergi)

Comment: No, it's a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) only if you don't need the values any more *but* they are preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr1` is defined only within the scope of the `GlobalObject` function. If you want to access it globally, you need to have the `GlobalObject` function return a reference to it. Read up on [functional scope in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) for a better understanding of this. Currently your function returns an empty object. You want to do something like this:

```
...
return {
   "array1": arr1,
   "array2": arr2,
   "array3": arr3,
   "array4": arr4
};
```

(though you can maintain the *privacy* of those arrays by not returning them)

The `GlobalObject` will maintain `arr1`'s reference and value until you manually de-reference it (setting it to `null`). [Javascript's garbage collector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Memory_Management) only deletes objects that aren't needed anymore.

Your current code shows no memory leaks. Watch out for [circular references and closures](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/).

Comment: Circular references are only dangerous if they include DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't unless `arr1` is exposed as a value of a property of the returned object
2. Yes
3. That depends on the rest of your code

For (1), you'd have to make sure that one of the properties of the object returned is a reference to the array:

```
    // ...
    return {
      whatever: arr1,
      // ...
    };
```

As to memory leaks, there's nothing about a setup like this that's particularly problematic.

Comment: Can you show mt the code for point 1 and for your third question... if i calling a function which is in another class[revealing module pattern]... will that cause problem in terms of leaks.

Comment: @Kevin answer updated. The memory leak question is completely dependent on other code; there's nothing special about objects created this way.